# Freeing TRIE structure in C recursively

Tags: c, recursion, trie

I'm currently trying, to no avail, to successfully free a `TRIE structure` using a `recursive function`, but I'm seeing memory loss.

The trie structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
}
node;
```

and I have the following Node* declared globally:

```
node* trie = NULL;
node* root = NULL;
```

The second is used only to keep track of the root node and first one is receiving words from a file. To this point I was getting no errors when compiling my program without freeing the heap memory, other than memory loss.

After implementing an unload( ) function, I started coming across `Segmentation Fault` errors.

See a snippet of my code:

```
/*
Frees node by node recursively
*/

bool freeSpace(node* child)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if(trie->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            freeSpace(trie->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(trie);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */ 
bool unload()
{

    if(root != NULL)
    {
        trie = root;
        freeSpace(trie);

        if(freeSpace(trie))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Maybe my code is not very smart at the returning values and validation, but my main issue now is guaranteeing the recursion works as intended and no memory is leaking or segmentation fault is occurring. Any advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you freeing it twice? `freeSpace(trie);

        if(freeSpace(trie))...`

Comment: Why do you call `freeSpace` __twice__ in your `unload` function? The second time, you _will_ receive a segfault, of course

Comment: Should `bool freeSpace(node* child)` be `bool freeSpace(node* trie)`? Otherwise, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Why does `freeSpace` need to return a value at all?

Comment: @IanAbbott `trie` is global variable, so `child` is redundant variable here.

Comment: Well.. That's *very* bad then. You are passing children to it hoping it will free them, and not the global variable. This is not how recursion works... Update @FilipKočica wait.. you are not the OP...

Comment: Haha got you. Kidding, it is wrote that `trie` and `root` are global variables.

Comment: @FilipKočica It shouldn't matter what the parameter of `freeSpace` is called as it will override a global variable of the same name.

Comment: @IanAbbott I know iam just saying that variable `child` is redundant becouse isnt used in function `freeSpace`. :-)

Comment: You *do* know that it is perfectly legal to pass `NULL` to `free()`? As in, your `freeSpace()` function can be rewritten to be quite a bit simpler?

Comment: Why does `freeSpace()` return a value when the only value it returns is `true`?  It would be better and simpler if the function had a return type of `void`.  Then calling code wouldn't test the return value, only to find it is never false.  If there's nothing to return, a function shouldn't return anything.  (Also think about how you'd document the correct use of the function — it returns a boolean: what does that mean, and how do you test the result and what do you do when it is false, and when it is true?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code snippet that makes more sense:

```
/*
Frees node by node recursively
*/

void freeSpace(node* t)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if(t->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            freeSpace(t->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(t);
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory. Returns true if successful else false.
 */ 
bool unload()
{

    if(root != NULL)
    {
        trie = root;
        freeSpace(trie);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The `freeSpace` function has been changed to use the parameter as the base of the trie to be freed.  Your original version had an unused parameter `child` and used global variable `trie` instead, which didn't make sense.

There is no need for `freeSpace` to return a value as all it does is free stuff, and it was only returning a fixed value `true`. I changed its return type to `void`.

Your `unload` function was calling `freeSpace` twice on the same object, so I removed one of the calls.

Comment: This looks so much better! I'll give it a try and see how it goes! Thx

My main issue here was I got overloaded with parameters and variables names and mix them all up. Now I see the rookie mistake I was doing. 

As per the true / false matter, yes, it was a big mess. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think your freeSpace() function should use **child parameter**  instead of trie. This is how it should look like.

```
bool freeSpace(node* child){   
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if(child->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            freeSpace(child->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(child);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ohh... I was for such a long time looking into this and implementing my whole program that I failed to notice I was not calling the structure I wanted inside the function and instead calling the value I was passing.

Comment: No problem. It happens. Just a quick suggestion, if you are comfortable with particular variable names then try to use that for parameters otherwise this happens. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at your code. Do you actually use the parameter to the function anywhere? You're actually always looking at the global trie pointer at each iteration, which isn't want you want to do.

To fix this, change your code so that you look at the node passed in as an argument and its children rather than the global trie pointer.

You have another issue to watch out for, and that's how you handle null pointers. Right now, you assume the argument pointer isn't null and then inspect each child to see whether it's non-null before recurring. But what if the trie itself is null to begin with? I'd consider creating a base case that checks if the trie is null and, if so, doesn't do anything. You can then eliminate the checks before the recursive calls you make and now properly guard against another edge case.